# How to disable auto-search & highlight in XAML editor, Visual Studio '22

Tags: visual-studio

When I click on a control in the XAML designer, that item's corresponding line in the XAML editor is also highlighted (by default in blue). That is great. But the editor also seems to perform an auto-search and highlights all of those results as well (by default in light gray).

For example, if I click on a button control in the XAML designer, the XAML editor moves to the corresponding row for the selected button and highlights the selected button in blue. But it also searches for every other occurrence of the text "button" and highlights it in light gray. It even highlights partial matches like ToggleButton. Is there a way to stop this auto-search and highlight?